# Windows Batch script to read first 10 lines from a 10GB Informatica session log

Tags: windows, batch-file

the for loop in windows batch console hangs and does not work while processing huge files of 10 gb but works with smaller files less than 1 gb. Eg

```
FOR /F "delims=]" %%A IN (dummy.txt) DO ( 
...code...
)
```

I need a batch script that will read first 10 lines of a code from a 10 gb  Informatica session log file efficiently. Is there any way to read huge files using batch programming ??

Comment: In case you have the possibility to use Linux related programs (a Cygwin emulator, a Ubuntu app, ...), you might use the Linux `head -10 <filename>` feature.

Comment: @Dominique... or simply use powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read first 10 lines
(for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do set /P "line[%%i]=") < dummy.txt

rem Process them
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   echo Line %%i- !line[%%i]!
   FOR /F "delims=]" %%A IN ("!line[%%i]!") DO (
      ...code...
   )
)
```

PS - I would bet this method run *much faster* than the PowerShell one!  **`;)`**

Comment: I would like that the downvoter explain the reasons he/she had to downvote a working solution... **`:(`**  Perhaps it was because the PS comment (GB)?  **`:/`**

Comment: why is it faster? `Get-Content` can filter the result while reading so I thought it should be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use powershell for this. there are 2 basic methods:
Open powershell. `Start`, `run(search)`, `poweshell.exe`. Then `cd` to the relevant directory and then run:

```
Get-Content dummy.txt | Select-Object -first 10
```

or save the above in a file with a `.ps1` extenion and simply run it from there.

If you still want to use it from within a batch file, simply make some additions like below and save as a `.bat` or `.cmd` file.

```
powershell -command "& {Get-Content dummy.txt | Select-Object -first 10}"
```

If you have powershell 3 or later, you can use the new head function built-in.

from batch:

```
powershell -command "& {Get-Content dummy.txt -Head 10}"
```

Or again as pure powershell:

```
Get-Content dummy.txt -Head 10
```

Comment: Just a question: the original issue was that the file is that large that reading it into memory causes a problem. You propose to filter the content, but only after having performed the `Get-Content` command. Won't you fall into the same issue?

Comment: @Dominique It does not get the entire content at once and still runs quick enough.

Comment: The documentation mentions a parameter `-ReadCount`, which is there, especially for working with large files. This might help the OP to solve the original issue. (Documentation URL: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6").

Comment: shorter version: `gc dummy.txt -H 10` or `cat dummy.txt -To 10`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have one issue. Im using the following command:  powershell -command "& {Get-Content dummy.txt | Select-Object -first 10  | Out-File "file.txt" }" .   But the process is not exiting automatically. How do I schedule it to run for 10 seconds and exit forcefully in cmd ??

Comment: @rounakchourasia try: `powershell -command "& {Get-Content dummy.txt | Select-Object -first 10}" > file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To read from a huge file you can use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and abort it using [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html):

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "COUNT=0, LIMIT=10"
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("huge.txt") do (
    set /A "COUNT+=1" & set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    rem // Do something with the current line:
    echo Line !COUNT!: !LINE!

    if !COUNT! geq !LIMIT! goto :QUIT
    endlocal
)
:QUIT
```

The greatest possible length of each line is about 8190 bytes or characters. Empty lines are ignored by `for /F` and therefore not counted.